# Migrate "everything" from single HDD setup to RAID5 using GUI

Tags: hard-drive, raid, qnap

I've got a QNAP TS-431XeU running QTS 5.0.
I've used it with a single HDD installed: 1 storage pool, 1 HDD, raid type Single, 1 thick system volume for everything.

Now I'm looking to size up and turn it into RAID5 with 4x of the same HDDs (I've purchased 3 more of the same model that I have).

How can I migrate all my data, shared folders, and the system using QNAP web GUI into a new setup leveraging all my HDDs? I'm not an expert in SSH (and, frankly, scared that doing it once will mess up my ability to go back to the GUI), thus would prefer a WebUI-based solution.

Comment: Don't forget to make a backup first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this document [Online RAID Level Migration](https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/tutorial/article/online-raid-level-migration) you can easily expand to RAID 5 without downtime and without any data loss. But backing up important data is certainly good advice.

Scroll down to:

> Use Online RAID Level Migration and RAID Capacity Expansion Together

> - first use "Online RAID Level Migration" to migrate the system from "Single Disk" to "RAID 1"
> - then run agin "Online RAID Level Migration" to migrate the system from "RAID 1" to "RAID 5"

You can skip the final step of hot swapping one disk explained there because you already start with identical disks and want to keep the four.